# SQL show records that don't exist in my table variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a table variable that holds `orderID`, `UnitID` and `OrderServiceId` (it is already populated via a query with insert statement).

I then have a query under this that returns 15 columns which also include the `OrderId`, `UnitId`, `OrderServiceId`

I need to only return the rows from this query where the same combination of `OrderId`, `UnitId`, and `OrderServiceId` are not in the table variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS`. e.g.

```
FROM YourQuery q
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(
SELECT * FROM @TableVar t
WHERE t.OrderId = q.OrderId
  and t.UnitId = q.UnitId 
  and t.OrderServiceId=q.OrderServiceId
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select q.*
from (
    MyQuery
) q
left outer join MyTableVariable t on q.ORDERID  = t.ORDERID
    and q.UNITID= t.UNITID
    and q.ORDERSERVICESID = t.ORDERSERVICESID 
where t.ORDERID is null
```

Comment: might give duplicates because it's a JOIN. Use NOT EXISTS

Answer (score 0):

You can use EXCEPT | INTERSECT operators for this [(link)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx).

Example:

```
(select 3,4,1
union all
select 2,4,1)

intersect

(select 1,2,9
union all
select 3,4,1)
```